Is it possible to get a graphQL response without the hierarchical clutter?
I'm trying to run some graphQL queries on the GitHub API.
For example, the following query will return the contents of a repository's README.md file:
query GetReadmeMD($owner: String!, $repo: String!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
        object(expression: "HEAD:README.md") {
            ... on Blob {
                text
            }
        }
    }
}

Or, rather, it will return a JSON object which contains the README, deep down:
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "object": {
                "text": "# My project's README [...]"
            }
        }
    }
}

Is there some way to skip all the hierarchical clutter and just get the thing I'm actually interested in (preferably with a raw POST, but using Python libraries is also acceptable), like this:
{
    "text": "# My project's README [...]"
}

The solution would need to allow specifying multiple different "values of interest".
The best I've managed so far is to:

use aliases with a known prefix to "tag" all the values of interest in my query
walk through the output and "collect" all the values with that prefix (in Python)

Modifying the query above to also collect the number of open PRs, and prefixing both values of interest with FOO_:
query GetReadmeMD($owner: String!, $repo: String!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
        pullRequests(states: OPEN) {
            FOO_n_open_prs: totalCount
        }
        object(expression: "HEAD:README.md") {
            ... on Blob {
                FOO_readme: text
            }
        }
    }
}

I can then parse the output and store only the keys with that prefix (while dropping the prefix itself):
{
    "n_open_prs": 42,
    "readme": "# My project's README [...]"
}

However, this solution feels clunky and awkward... I'm wondering if I'm just ignorant on something basic about graphQL (quite likely, since I started learning it this week), or if I'm reinventing a worse version of the wheel.
